# A simple Lie algebra with modules of a particular type

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, lie-algebras

I’m trying to copy the following construction of P. Forster in group theory for Lie algebras. He takes a non-abelian simple group E which has an FpE-module V such that R = Rad(V ) is faithful and irreducible as an FpE-module and V/R is an irreducible trivial FpE-module. Let H  be the semidirect product V ⋋ E. Then H′ = RE (here the dash denotes the derived subgroup) is a primitive group and |H : H′ | = p. Next he takes an FqH-module W  with centralizer equal to H′  where q \neq p. He then forms the semidirect product W ⋋H. He doesn’t appear to say explicitly which group E  is. Does anyone know of a simple Lie algebra over a field of characteristic p  for which a similar construction may be possible?

Comment: I don't know what it means in terms of Lie algebras, but that construction works for any choice of finite non-Abelian simple group $E$ whose order is divisible by $p$. The key point is that the projective cover of the trivial module has a non-trivial (hence faithful) simple module as a composition factor.

Comment: Thank you Geoff. It helps to have a better understanding of the group-theoretic situation.

Comment: Forster uses this construction to show that F*(F*(G)) < F*(G) where F*(G) is a generalised Fitting subgroup (not the quasinilpotent radical). I find his paper hard to follow as my German is very poor. A similar construction for Lie algebras, which looks possible using projective covers, could produce a Lie algebra with interesting properties.